# Percentage padding of multiline block

Tags: css, responsive-design, height, padding

Can I set padding which depending on height of multiline text?
For example, I need `padding-top` of `div.p` less and less for each new line.

```css
 .modal{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    float: left;
}
.p{
    position: relative;
}
.p:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc((120px - 100%) / 5); /*not working*/
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="h"><b>Header</b></div>
        <div class="p">Multiline text. Multiline text.</div>
    </div>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

More examples: https://jsfiddle.net/1n4bdtea/ (I want a padding between text and header ~10x for 1 line and ~5px for 4 lines)

Comment: is this the actual requirement or what you're trying to accomplish is to align the button of all the div in a same line?

Comment: Alignment required. I need equal padding for top->header, bottom->button, button->text